# Connect several strings into one string in R

Tags: string, r, merge, character

I know that paste() can connect several strings into one string. For example

```
> paste("a", "b", "c")
[1] "a b c"
```

Now, I have a vector

```
c = c("a", "b", "c")
```

I want to convert c into "abc", I cannot use paste(c), which will do nothing to c.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `collapse` parameter:

```
paste(c("a", "b", "c"), collapse=" ")
# [1] "a b c"
```

Comment: How could I forget it again! Thanks!